# Best Approach to manipulate level colors in a scatterplot - ggplot2 (layering plots and/or assigning colors to specific row values/or something else?)

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, psychtoolbox

Here is a sample of my data frame:

```
HRdetails <- data.frame(avgHR = c(96,115,130,120,112,87,112,114,116,140),
                   DetailCount = c(5,18,4,3,9,2,10,11,19,15),
                   PID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2), 
                   Section = c("lab","s1","s2","s3","s4","lab","s1","s2","s3","s4"))
data$Section<-as.factor(data$Section)
data$PID<-as.factor(data$PID)
data$DetailCount<-as.integer(data$DetailCount)
```

I am plotting a scatterplot with individual prediction lines for each participant and an overall regression line for the sample.

Here is a picture of my plot:

[image]

This is the code I am using to plot the above figure:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = avgHR, y = DetailCount)) +
   geom_point(aes(colour=factor(PID)), method="lm", alpha=.75,size = 2) +
   scale_color_manual(values=coul) +
   geom_smooth(aes(colour=factor(PID)), method="lm", alpha=.75,size = .5, se=F) +
   geom_smooth(method="lm", color="black") +
   theme(legend.position="none")
```

the variable `coul` is my custom palette:

```
coul<-c("#666699","#CCCCFF","#996699","#FFFFCC","#99CC99","#336666","#006699","#000066")
coul<-colorRampPalette(coul)(50)
pie(rep(1, length(coul)), col = coul, main="")
```

As you can see in the df, one of the levels in the "Section" factor is labeled "lab". I want my figure to have all points for the other "Sections" to be colored from the `coul` palette I made, but I want all of the "lab" sections to be colored from this `lab` palette:

```
lab<-brewer.pal(n=9, name="YlOrRd")
lab<-colorRampPalette(lab)(45)
pie(rep(1, length(lab)), col=lab, main="")
```

If I were plotting the lab points alone, this is what the scatterplot looks like:
[image]

Here is the code for that scatterplot:

```
ggplot(data=labstats, aes(x=avgHR, y=DetailCount)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=factor(PID))) +
  scale_color_manual(values=lab) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

And here is a picture of the lab only Df I am using for that:

[image]

What is the best approach to making a plot that shows all the lab points in my `lab` palette and the rest of the points in the `coul` palette?

I have been looking into stacking the plots on top of each other because that theoretically seems easiest, but I am having a very difficult time figuring out how to combine these without error and using two different dfs. I also considered assigning the `lab` palette to specific row values within the original model visualization, but that seems difficult/I don't think ggplot is equipped to do that. **Please** correct me if I am wrong and/or help me figure this out. ALSO, I am using palettes because each participant needs to have their own discrete color values for each datapoint. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want a unique color per Section and PID, you can define an interaction. To get the correct color per interaction, you can create a named vector, and then provide that named vector to scale_color_manual.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(scales) # only used to display color palettes for debugging purposes

data <- data.frame(avgHR = c(96,115,130,120,112,87,112,114,116,140),
                        DetailCount = c(5,18,4,3,9,2,10,11,19,15),
                        PID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2), 
                        Section = c("lab","s1","s2","s3","s4","lab","s1","s2","s3","s4"))
data$Section<-as.factor(data$Section)
data$PID<-as.factor(data$PID)
data$DetailCount<-as.integer(data$DetailCount)

# generate palettes per group
num_lab <- sum(data$Section == 'lab')
num_non_lab <- sum(data$Section != 'lab')

coul<-c("#666699","#CCCCFF","#996699","#FFFFCC","#99CC99","#336666","#006699","#000066")
coul<-colorRampPalette(coul)(sum(data$Section != 'lab'))

lab<-brewer.pal(n=9, name="YlOrRd")
lab<-colorRampPalette(lab)(sum(data$Section == 'lab'))

# display the color palettes
show_col(coul)
show_col(lab)

# create the combined palette, where participants from each group get assigned a color from
# the palette for their group
color_palette <- array(NA, nrow(data))
color_palette[data$Section == 'lab'] <- lab
color_palette[data$Section != 'lab'] <- coul
names(color_palette) <- interaction(data$PID, data$Section)

# plot the data
ggplot(data <- data, aes(x = avgHR, y = DetailCount, color = interaction(PID, Section))) +
  geom_point() + scale_color_manual(values=color_palette)
```

[image]

I also noticed during plotting that the palettes for lab and non-lab share a color, (hex #FFFFCC). You should likely choose different color palettes that won't overlap. This is why that color appears for dots in both lab and non-lab.

'Coul' Palette:

[image]

'Lab' Palette:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input! When I try this, it just creates a large figure using the colors from the lab palette. Do you have any troubleshooting ideas? Ideally, each participant will have unique colors per data point per section. I am not quite sure why it is not varying in color per data point.

Comment: It would be easier to debug if you could post at least a small snippet of the data frame you are using as text, rather than an screenshot.

Comment: I think the issue is that I originally assumed that each participant was only in one Section, I see from the data you posted that is not the case, I'll update my answer.

Comment: That was super helpful - it worked! Thank you so much. Follow-up question: Do you know how I can add individual regression lines for each participant? I was using this line: geom_smooth(aes(colour=factor(PID)), method="lm", alpha=.75,size = .5, se=F) - but now it is claiming there are not enough values in the manual scale to do them @DMR

Comment: What color do you want the lines to be? For example in the plot shown above, a giving participant has multiple colors for their points, since they have data from multiple sections. Should the lines for that participant be one of those multiple colors? Or some other color like black?

Comment: I would like each participant line to be one of multiple colors that is specific to that participant (preferably from the coul palette instead of the lab palette) @DMR